# Bootstrap tooltip glitch using input-group-addon in Safari

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to implement a tooltip on an `input-group-addon`.
While everything works, I notice a glitch in **Safari**: the `input-group-addon` starts jumping to the left when hovering it.

I'm not seeing this behaviour on Chrome.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?
Here's a Fiddle which demonstrates my problem:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nxd9akm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  placement: 'bottom',
  container: 'body'
});
```

> #### Tooltips in button groups, input groups, and tables require special setting
>
> When using tooltips on elements within a `.btn-group` or an `.input-group`, or on table-related elements (`<td>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`), you'll have to specify the option `container: 'body'` (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is triggered).